# Using event listeners with React.useEffect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrappedcomponentref-in-function-component-rmxlz?file=/src/index.tsx)

Hi, I want to create a container so that if you click the button inside of the container, a box appears. I have added an event listener so that if you mouse out of the container, the box will no longer show. Of course, I need to also add an event listener to the button inside of the container so that hovering over the button won't hide the box if you have the box already visible.

However, I am having difficulty with this and am seeing some side effects. For example, if you as  click the button to show the box, and then click it again to hide the box, then hovering over the button will show the box again, which is not the desired affect.

I believe there is something I am doing wrong using React.useEffect and not tracking state properly, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a `useEffect` that manually adds some kind of event listener, 99% of the time you *must* have it return a cleanup function that will remove said event listener. Otherwise you end up with dangling event listeners that haven't been cleaned up between `useEffect` calls.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleButtonMouseOver = (): void => {
      if (show) {
        setShow(true);
      }
    };

    // const handleMouseOut = (): void => {
    //   if (show) {
    //     setShow(false);
    //   }
    // };

    // Save reference to this element in the scope of the function
    // buttonRef.current may change between triggers
    const buttonElement = buttonRef.current;

    if (buttonElement) {
      buttonElement.addEventListener("mouseover", handleButtonMouseOver);
    }

    // if (containerRef.current) {
    //   containerRef.current.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
    // }

    // Add this
    return () => {
      buttonElement.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleButtonMouseOver);
    };
  }, [buttonRef, containerRef, show]);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup